# How to prevent caret misplacement when deleting elements in a contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

My application includes a typeahead feature when a user is typing into a comment box.  In a similar fashion to Facebook's and google+'s it will perform a lookup of users and suggest them as tags on the fly.

When a user selects one of the offered tags it gets entered into the input area as an  element.

I decided to use a conenteditable div for this, but have come across a few issues.

It turns out that firefox wont delete the inserted elements when they are set to contenteditable false whereas every other major browser does.

In order to work around this I have set the inserted 'user' tags as contenteditble=true and wrote a quick jquery workaround to solve this issue.

It works perfectly apart from one major issue.  If there are multiple tags in the area and the first of them is not proceeded by any text, then when the user deletes the final one (assuming deletion with the backspace key from right to left) the caret gets positioned incorrectly following that final deletion.

Typing again appears to then return the position to normal.

**This issue only occurs in Firefox**

Here is a jsFiddle showing the issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/gordyr/PESky/

Place your cursor at the end of that last tag and then hold down the backspace key until all elements are removed.  You will see that the cursor/caret moves up and out of position.

It is quite possible that this is actually a bug in firefox itself, however I am looking for a workaround of some kind as without this automatic element deletion with javascript, the don't get removed at all.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that FF leaves some dirt behind, but you can clean it up by adding:

```
if (!$.trim(el.text())) {
    el.empty();
}
```

This will check if the innerText of the contenteditable only contains spaces or newlines/breaks. If it does, just empty it. Seems to work in my test: http://jsfiddle.net/cBZ7k/

**Side note**: you should probably use `keydown` instead of `keypress` for webkit support. Also, `e.which` is enough to get the keyCode, jQuery normalizes this event property for you.

Comment: Absolutely perfect! I had played around with similar ideas but hadn't quit hit on using trim for some silly reason.  It works perfectly, thank you.  This code is a polyfill for firefox as all other browsers seem to behave properly...  Regardless I was under the impression that keypress was considered best practice and I had no idea that jQuery normalizes e.which...  Great info.  Thanks for your help, i'll accept the answer asap.

Comment: IMO contenteditable is great, but since it supports "rich text" it can also be filled with a lot of dirty stuff by user input.

Comment: Indeed, it certainly seems that way... great learning for me. cheers David.

Comment: i have a `span` element in a container `div`. the `span` is `contenteditable`. the text in the span is centered vertically by applying `display: flex`, `align-items: center`, and `height: 100%` to the `span` element. however, when all of the characters are deleted, the caret jumps to the upperleft corner as if text would not be vertically centered if there were still text. any idea how to fix this?